# Using a variable in a regex

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

How can I use a variable string in a regular expressions?

```
while read line
do
    if [[ line =~ *"$key"* ]]; then
        echo line
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

`$key` is a string variable and I want to print all the lines that has the value of `$key`.

Comment: Are you sure about that pattern?  `*$key*` would be quite the odd pattern to match if `$key` were something like `^foo` or `foo$`, resulting in a pattern of `*^foo*` or `*foo$*`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti The question is about why the script doesn't work, and those errors you fixed in your edit are why it doesn't. Editing the question to fix the errors actually renders the question useless...

Comment: My apologies for the faux-pas.

Comment: @DopeGhoti No problem. Edits to fix errors like that are generally welcome in answers. You probably want to be wary of editing code in questions, as the error might be the cause of the problem. Of course, feel free to fix grammar, spelling, formatting, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've made a few mistakes there. Here's your script corrected:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $key ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

Though it seems it could be replaced with a simple `grep`:

```
grep "$key" "$filename"
```

Comment: `grep "$key" "$filename"` is not exactly equivalent, since in this context, `$key` is interpreted as a BRE. Use `-F` to avoid this.

Comment: the grep works fine but the while loop isn't doing anything, thanks though!

Comment: @user2798694: that's what Janos meant ^^ : no longer use the "while ..... done", but instead just use: `grep "$key" "$filename"` . grep will only output lines matching $key in the file $filename, which seems to be what you were trying to do? [unless you wanted to do additionnal things for each matched lines?]

Comment: There's a performance loss by using grep rather than the builtin.

Comment: This example no longer works with Bash versions >= 4.0.  If the right-hand side of the =~ operator is quoted, variable expansion is not performed.

Comment: @Bklyn, that actually changed in bash 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

First, whenever you're using the value of a variable, you need to write `$line`.

Also, note that `read line` strips off leading and trailing whitespace, and allows the sequence backslash-newline as a line continuation. To retain whitespace, use `IFS= read`. To avoid treating `\` specially, use `read -r`. You can of course combine the two as `IFS= read -r`.

What do you want to test exactly? If you want to test that the line is exactly `$key` (except for whitespace unless you use `IFS= read`), use the `==` operator, and make sure to put `$key` in double quotes.

```
if [[ $line == "$key" ]]; then …
```

If you want to test that the line contains `$key` (so for example if the value of `key` is `fu*bar` then `hellofu*bar` and `fu*barqux` match, but `fuubar` and `gu*bar` don't), then use the `==` operator and again make sure to put `$key` in double quotes. The right-hand side of the `==` operator is a shell wildcard pattern; putting the variable in double quotes causes it to be treated literally.

```
if [[ $line == *"$key"* ]]; then …
```

If you want to treat `$key` as a wildcard pattern, so that if `$key` is `fu*bar` then the line can be `fubar` or `fuqwebar` but not `fbar` or `afubar`, then leave off the double quotes:

```
if [[ $line == $key ]]; then …
```

If you only want part of the line to match, allowing things like `afubar`:

```
if [[ $line == *$key* ]]; then …
```

Use the regular expression match operator `=~` if you want to have an [extended regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) on the right-hand side. A regular expression can match part of the line; if you want to match the whole line, put `^` at the beginning of the regex and `$` at the end. For example, `[[ $line == *"$key"* ]]` is equivalent to `[[ $line =~ "$key" ]]` while `[[ $line == "$key" ]]` is equivalent to `[[ $line =~ ^"$key"$ ]]`.