# Why does the regex in bash works only if it is a variable and not directly?

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, string

So why does the following works i.e. prints out the match:

```
THE_REGEX='^test\/version[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+$'
if [[ "$SOME_VAR" =~ $THE_REGEX ]]; then
    echo "Match!"
fi
```

But the following does NOT:

```
if [[ "$SOME_VAR" =~ '^test\/version[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+$' ]]; then
    echo "Match!"
fi
```

What is the difference? It is the same regex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use the single quotes inside `[[`:

```
if [[ "$SOME_VAR" =~ ^test\/version[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+$ ]]; then
    echo "Match!"
fi
```

---

From the GNU bash manual:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs

Note in particular:

> **Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string**.

The manual seems to suggest using the variable is preferred:

> Storing the regular expression in a shell variable is often a useful way to avoid problems with quoting characters that are special to the shell. It is sometimes difficult to specify a regular expression literally without using quotes, or to keep track of the quoting used by regular expressions while paying attention to the shell’s quote removal. Using a shell variable to store the pattern decreases these problems.

See also [How does storing the regular expression in a shell variable avoid problems with quoting characters that are special to the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382054/9537)