# bash regexp matching fails in [[ ]]

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I would like to check whether a user is in a certain group via

```
[[ "$(getent group groupname)" =~ \busername\b ]]
```

but this does not work (bash 5.0.3) although the following works:

```
getent group groupname | grep -E "\busername\b"
```

I noticed that the backslashes appear to be swallowed at some place

```
bash -cx '[[ "$(getent group groupname)" =~ \busername\b ]]'
++ getent group groupname
+ [[ groupname:x:24:username =~ busernameb ]]
```

but this could also be an effect of `-x`.

Can anyone clear this up? :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `bash`, `\` is a quoting operator like `'` and `"`. So:

```
[[ "$(getent group groupname)" =~ \busername\b ]]
```

is the same as:

```
[[ "$(getent group groupname)" =~ 'b'username'b' ]]
```

Since `bash` 3.2, bash makes sure than when you quote a character in a regexp, it removes its special meaning as a regexp operator if it had one (which is not the case of `b`).

In `bash` 3.1, you would have been able to do:

```
[[ "$(getent group groupname)" =~ '\busername\b' ]]
```

And you can still do if you turn on the `bash31` option or set `$BASH_COMPAT` to `3.1`. That would also work in `zsh`.

That would have worked on systems where the system extended regular expression library  supports that `\b` non-standard extension (like on recent GNU systems).

In bash 3.2 and above, that doesn't work because by quoting the `\`, bash removes the specialness of `\` as a regex operator (in effect it calls the regex library  with `\\busername\\b`.

What you can do though is write it:

```
regexp='\<username\>' # here using the slightly more portable \< \> instead of \b
[[ "$(getent group groupname)" =~ $regexp ]] # make sure $regexp is *not* quoted
```

Then it would work with both bash 3.1 and bash 3.2+ (and zsh and ksh93). See [How does storing the regular expression in a shell variable avoid problems with quoting characters that are special to the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382054) for more details on that.

Here though, I'd use standard `sh` syntax and do:

```
group=groupname
user=username

group_definition=$(getent -- group "$group") || exit
case ,${group_definition##*:}, in
  (*,"$user",*) printf '%s\n' "$user is in the $group group\n"
esac
```

Which also works more reliably if the user name contains regexp operators (`.` is common in user names) or the user name happens to be the same as the group name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This change in 3.2 seems quite unfortunate regarding the `=~` operator considering that you always have to create a regexp-variable first.

Comment: @Suuuehgi, yes, I kind of agree. See also my latest edit and  [Why isn't \`|\` treated literally in a glob pattern?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/382307) or [Which regular expression methods to validate input could be used in shell scripting?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/140716) or https://osdn.net/projects/yash/ticket/39094

Comment: I have spent SO MANY HOURS because `\s` doesn't work in `[[ $var =~ regex ]]` when it's not in a variable